# Center header text in a container on mobile

Tags: css, mobile, header, containers, centering

The text in this header centers just fine until you shrink the width of the page, then it just moves the text to the right.

You can test it here:
http://jsfiddle.net/ors2gqey/

```css
.header {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.headerImg {
  padding: 200px;
  background-image: url("header.jpg");
  background-position: 50% 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  text-align: center;
}

.header h1 {
  min-width: 140px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 4.5em;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="headerImg">
    <h1>TEST TEXT</h1>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: On small screens, the 200px padding doesn't fit anymore. Use a media query to change the amount of padding for smaller screens.

Comment: Id like to keep the header size pretty big. I tried adding min-height but then the text isnt centered vertically. Is there a way to overcome that?

Comment: The way you have defined padding, it uses 200px on top, right, bottom and left. You could probably just use it for top and bottom: padding: 200px 0;

Comment: Oh, thanks alot! Thats exactly what I was looking for. Kinda a silly mistake from me but thanks alot again for clearing it up for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I used padding on all sides.

Solved with just using padding on the top and bottom:

```
.headerImg {
    padding-top: 200px;
    padding-bottom: 200px;
    background-image: url("header.jpg");
    background-position: 50% 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> @media (max-width: 600px) {
>     .headerImg {
>         padding: 0;
>     } 
> }
> ```

```css
.header {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.headerImg {
  padding: 200px;
  background-image: url("header.jpg");
  background-position: 50% 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .headerImg {
        padding: 0;
     }
}

.header h1 {
  min-width: 140px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-size: 4.5em;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="headerImg">
    <h1>TEST TEXT</h1>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: just test the query with full page link